# Direct link to language in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, multilingual

I have a website(built with OpenCart) with multiple languages, e.g. English, German, French.
Users can change language using default functionality of the OpenCart - clicking on language icons on top.

Is it possible to send users automaticaly (so they don't have to click on the flag) from :
Germany to German version of the website
France to French version of the website
(English language is default)

Is there an URL I can use for these languages if the default page is for example http://mystore.com ?
(I noticed that when I click on the language icon the URL is not changing - it's the same for all languages)

Comment: There is at least one [extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18641) I found that does this, but I would be interested in an answer from an OpenCart expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays opencart doesn't support this function, but in the past , older versions of Opencart did have this function.

If you want to include this function in your website you will have to do the following:

Edit this file:
catalog/controller/module/language.php

find this:

```
    class ControllerModuleLanguage extends Controller {
        protected function index() {
            if (isset($this->request->post['language_code'])) {
```

before the "if", you will have to include the following :

```
if (isset($this->request->get['lang'])) {

    $this->session->data['language'] = $this->request->get['lang'];

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->config->get('config_url')) !== false) ) {

        $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    } else {

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('common/home'));

    }

} else  {
```

[The source](http://www.codigojavaoracle.com/desarrollo-web/opencart-url-para-diferentes-lenguajes)

An example of website with this code:

http://incomingtospain.com/madrid&lang=de

http://incomingtospain.com/madrid&lang=ru

This website has 8 idioms and you can access by different url, with this variable "lang" &lang=es &lang=en ... &lang=de &lang=ru

Answer (score 0):

I think language is set in session variable

For the functionality you mentioned will be achive in following way:

1. Use the HTML5 geolocation to detect the location of user
2. Research in opencart to set the language function
3. after all done place your code using VQMOD if you want to do it in proper way
   or you can also edit your core opencart files( Not recommended)
4. if the browser doesn't support geolocation or they refuse to share their location just load the default language.

Answer (score -1):

With OpenCart 2.0, you must work on the file index.php (in your website root) and place this code :

```
if (isset($request->get['lang']) && array_key_exists($request->get['lang'], $languages)) {

    $session->data['language'] = $request->get['lang'];

}
```

between line 155 and line 157

Line 153 to 154 :

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {

$languages[$result['code']] = $result;

}
```

(you add here the new code)

Line 157 :

`if (isset($session->data['language']) && array_key_exists($session->data['language'], $languages)) {`

Line 158 :

```
$code = $session->data['language'];
```